# How to use Firebase Firestore's `docChanges` method?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

in an action in a react native app using `react-native-firebase`, I create a Firestore snapshot listener:

listener:

```
export const onAgendaChange = (uid, role, dispatch) => {
    // query based off role
    let query;
    if (role == 'Receiver') {
        query = 'receiver.uid';
    } else {
        query = 'sender.uid';
    }

    console.log('(actions/agenda) Firestore Read: getAgenda()');

    return firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('events')
        .where(query, '==', uid)
        .orderBy('date')
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            const agenda = []

            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                let event = doc.data();
                event.id = doc.id;
                agenda.push(event);

                dispatch({ type: types.LOAD_AGENDA_SUCCESS, payload: agenda });
            });

            querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(function (change) {
                if (change.type === "added") {
                    console.log("Add heard: ", change.doc.data());
                }
                if (change.type === "modified") {
                    console.log("Modified heard: ", change.doc.data());
                }
                if (change.type === "removed") {
                    console.log("Removed heard: ", change.doc.data());
                }
            });
        });
};
```

one problem im observing is on initial app load, when this listener executes, it returns an error:

> TypeError: querySnapshot.docChanges is not a function. (In
> 'querySnapshot.docChanges()', 'querySnapshot.docChanges' is an
> instance of Array)

the next issue im observing is that, if the app is reloaded, the error above is not generated, so if a document in the collection referenced is changed, the `docChanges()` still does not log anything. this is taken directly from firebase docs. And when using `onSnapshot()` on 'where' or 'orderBy', the callback receives a querySnapshot object, which does indeed have `docChanges()` as a method. So any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that message is referring to this code?

Comment: @DougStevenson if I remove the use of `docChanges()`,  no issue

Comment: docChanges should always be a function and never an array.  If you have a reproducible example suggesting otherwise, that's a bug report you can file with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: this is using react-native-firebase, do you think thats relevant?

Comment: Maybe.  Tag the question as such, though.

Comment: good point. I forgot im even using that library sometimes, since its almost an exact mirror

Answer (score 3):

This issue is a result of following firebase docs too closely, while using react-native-firebase.

While the library does mirror 95% of firebase docs, in this case, it doesn't.

with react-native-firebase, `docChanges` is a property, not a function, so you want to use:

```
querySnapshot.docChanges.forEach(function (change) {
  if (change.type === "added") {
    console.log("Add heard: ", change.doc.data());
  }
  if (change.type === "modified") {
    console.log("Modified heard: ", change.doc.data());
  }
  if (change.type === "removed") {
    console.log("Removed heard: ", change.doc.data());
  }
});
```

Comment: Looks like you're still calling docChangse as a function here.